# Getting HTTP Status 404 error when trying to deploy war file of my web application on tomcat

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I know this questions was asked earlier yet any of the answers given did not fix my problem.

I have created a web application named JSP_web_application_01 using JSP in Eclipse and I'm on ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have index.jsp file inside WebContent directory. I made the .war file of it using command prompt and in order to deploy it I put it inside the webapps folder of tomcat and stopped tomcat using the command  sudo $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh and again started it by sudo $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh

And it inflated the .war file(JSP_web_application_01.war) and created the JSP_web_application_01 folder structure and everything but what I get is an http 404 status code when I try to access it from the browser using :

```
http://localhost:8080/JSP_web_application_01/
```

I get this :

```
HTTP Status 404 - /JSP_web_application_01/
type Status report
message /JSP_web_application_01/
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
```

This is my web.xml file that is inside WebContent/WEB-INF folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>JSP_web_application_01</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

This is my first time of trying to host a web application. So, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "I made the .war file of it using command prompt"?

Answer (score 0):

Your Steps seems to be ok , Replace the welcome file list with a single file, If you want to load index.html . then  ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>JSP_web_application_01</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Also Clean and Build your project to get rid of errors before you deploy it as .war

Read  [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1026980) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deployment_descriptor) to know more about Deployment Descriptor.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check the project files must be decompressed under JSP_web_application_01 especially index.jsp. If it correct, restart web server, tail the log file under $CATALINA_HOME/logs, check the start info correct.