# 404 when application is deployed for the first time: how come?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I put my .war and start the server:

```
./bin/startup.sh
```

I go to the webpage where I expect to find my web application and I get a 404 not found.

So, I shutdown the server:

```
./bin/shutdown.sh
```

And bring it up again:

```
./bin/startup.sh
```

This time my web application starts fine.
Why?

Comment: Are there any error-messages in the server-log?

Comment: possible dupli : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896581/getting-http-status-404-error-when-trying-to-deploy-war-file-of-my-web-applicati

Comment: Clean and Build your project to get rid of errors before you deploy it as .war